# Find and Replace does not find anything on excel

Tags: excel, replace, find

I have a spreadsheet with data autogenerated by a system that has weird names. For example, in one column I have an entire column with "PQ_EUK_Name1".

I have tried to find and replace the first part of every cell "PQ_EUK_" to simply remove it all, as I don't need that.

However, when I search for "PQ" or "PQC*_EUK*" or any other iteration of this, the error is always the same, excel can't find anything.

I have changed the data to "General" and "Text" but no results so far.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Make sure you don't have "Match entire cell contents" checked.

Comment: Can't believe a simple thing has taken me this long... thank you, what a massive oversight. I need a nap.

Comment: What about `TEXTAFTER(A1, "PQ_EUK_")`? if you have the text in cell `A1`. This works under O365. Please try it and let us know. Thanks